# VSCode + Go keeps toggles go.mod dependencies, sets root ownership

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

There is a project that uses Go modules. There is a recent version of `VSCode` with the official Go extension installed.

### Problem 1

Every time the focus moves out of `VSCode` - it would update the modules files. E.g.:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

### Problem 2

Sometimes the ownership of `go.mod` would be set to `root` - breaking shell-scripts and overall working routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to keep in mind 2 things:

1. Make sure to update mod dependencies on a regular basis.
2. Make sure to set the user for Docker Compose fiels (by default Docker will use the 0:0 - root permission, modifying the files on the host system).